# Passport and visa requirement

Tags: visas

I am a citizen of St.Vincent and Antigua, I have a USA visa in my St.Vincent passport but I will be holidaying in the USA but I want to go over to Canada, can I use my Antigua passport to go to Canada because Antiguans don't need a visa for Canada. So my question is can I go into the usa on my St.Vincent passport then leave the usa on my Antigua passport for Canada?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is to present your St Vincent passport to US immigration as you enter and as you leave, and your Antiguan passport to Canadian customs as you enter Canada.

If you are travelling by air you may need to present your Antiguan passport to the airline, in order to prove you have permission to enter Canada.

Comment: There is no opportunity to present a passport to US immigration as one leaves the US.

Answer (score -2):

YOu should inquire at the immigration office on that matter for you to have such an honest and clear details about your concern.